# shell if-else issue with can't jump to else block

Tags: shell, if-statement

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter your MO or attribute name: " name
grep -q $name *.txt      #judge the input whether exists or not. if it exists , $? will equal 0, if not , $? will equal 1. 
echo $?
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
  echo "Send to file 2"
  echo $name >> 2.txt
else
  echo "Send to file 1"
  echo $name >> 1.txt
fi
```

Below is the program progress

```
Enter your MO or attribute name: sssqq
1                 #means no file contains "sssqqq"
Send to file 2

Enter your MO or attribute name: chenghuang
0                  #means some file contains "chenghuang"
Send to file 2
```

As you see, whether the input exists in the file or not , they all will be send to 2.txt. But my purpose is that if the input exists in the file , the input will be sent to file 2, if not, it will be sent to file 1.
what's wrong with if-else?

Comment: Remove the line `echo $?` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Save result to variable and manipulate with it:

```
res=$?
echo $res
if [ $res -eq 0 ];then
  echo "Send to file 2"
  echo $name >> 2.txt
else
  echo "Send to file 1"
  echo $name >> 1.txt
fi
```

The problem is that `echo $?` which you have called is replaced the previous result `$?` with its own new result.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is the use of `$?`. `$?` always holds the return value of the last command. After you run `echo $?`, the `$?` in your if statement holds the return value of `echo`.